# Are linearly independent vectors of a vector space also system of generators?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have three linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$, does it mean that they also are a system of generators for $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I know that a system of generators of a vector space can produce all the vectors that belong to a given vector space. I am wondering if *any* set of linearly independent vectors of a vector space is also considered a system of generators of that vector space. Any hints?

Comment: They generate generally a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *any* set of linearly independent vectors is automatically a generating set of the whole space is *false*. A set with a single nonzero vector is linearly independent, but it not necessarily true that is a generating set of all the vector space.

Consider $\{(1,0,0)\}$. This is clearly linearly independent but the vector $(2,5,7)$ cannot be written as a linear combination of only the vector $(1,0,0)$.